# jQuery - isSelector function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

I've failed to find anything which would be helpful in my particular situation, so here's a question: for a specific string how to check if it's a proper jQuery selector (for time being let's make it simple and restrain ourselves to noncustom jQuery selectors), or if that's too hard, valid CSS selector - basically:

```
$.isSelector("div") = return true
$.isSelector("* [") = return false - unclosed attribute selector
$.isSelector("* []") = return false - empty attribute selector
$.isSelector("* [name]") = return true
$.isSelector("/hiThere") = return false - invalid / character
$.isSelector("body > ") = return false - > without following child selector
$.isSelector("body > [name=\\\[girls_just_want_to_have_fun\\\]].on a .beach") = return true
```

Probably there's an internal jQuery function that does the check (or a RegExp), but my voodoo is too poor to find it.

Probably something like this:

```
function isSelector(string)
{ 
   try 
   { 
       $(string); 
       return true;
   } 
   catch(e) 
   { 
       return false; 
   }
}
```

would do the trick, but it seems a little extreme.

Cheers!

Comment: A basic usage would be <a href="#element"> which would display, in a modal, content of <div id="element"> if isSelector($(this).href), otherwise, if isUrl($(this).href) would load the content of /url/ via ajax, otherwise, if isNumeric($(this).href) would display $(this).href crocodiles.

Comment: As @karim79 notes in the comments under his answer, your best bet is going to be to just check the `length` of the jQuery object you get back

Comment: not really - isSelector('p') should return true even if my document doesn't contain paragraphs. Updated my question though with what I've come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this solution:

```
function isSelector(string)
{
    var ns = document.styleSheets[0];

    if (!ns)
    {
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
        ns = document.styleSheets[0];
    }

    try
    {
        ns.insertRule(string+" {}", 0);
        ns.deleteRule(0);

        return true;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Additionally, this (valid) example

```
isSelector('#\\~\\!\\@\\$\\%\\^\\&\\*\\(\\)\\_\\+-\\=\\,\\.\\/\\\'\\;\\:\\"\\?\\>\\<\\[\\]\\\\\\{\\}\\|\\`\\#')`
```

returns true

Answer (score 0):

> for a specific string how to check if it's a proper jQuery selector

You can't. Just about anything can be a selector, for example my page could consist of a bunch of `blah`s, which would make `$("blah")` perfectly valid.

jQuery does do some checking on the string you pass as argument, this happens within the `init` method of the core, which I have highlighted in source browser for you:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L78-186

Comment: Okay, but if that is the case then think about the unreliable regex hell you'll be delving in to to 'validate a selector string'.

Comment: Yes, XHTML is completely valid. You can CSS XHTML however, so I don't know why would it matter :)

I was hoping that jQuery has somekind of internal function that checks this kind of stuff, which handles things gracefully, instead of throwing exceptions when something goes wrong.

Comment: @eithed - it does not in order to maintain chaining. I can always do `$("foobar > [shizmo=derp *]").add(this).hide();` and if `this` is a valid element, it still gets hidden because jQuery always returns itself.

Comment: Huh? I don't have problems with `foobar > [shizmo=derp*]`, and as long it exists, `this` will be, and should be added to every such element, and yes, then it should hide `this`. However, if I were to do something like this: `$("foobar > [shizmo=derp*").add(this).hide()` I'd not expect jQuery to return an empty array. It should give me an exception, damnit...

Comment: @eithed - hehe, well, maybe you're better off simply checking if such elements exist by accessing the `.length` property of the jQuery object.